# Making sure that a script does not modify files in specific folder

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script which copies files from a server, performs a few operations on them, and delete the files locally after processing.
The script is not supposed to modify the files on the server in any way.

However, since bugs may occur, I would like to make sure that I'm not modifying\deleting the original server files.

Is there a way to prevent a python script from having writing permissions to a specific folder? I work on Windows OS.

Comment: You can `chmod` your server files. And set the Python script as another user without write permission.

Answer (score 0):

That is unrelated to Python, but to the filesystem security provided by the OS. The key is that permissions are not given to programs but to the user under which they run.

Windows provides the command `runas` that allows to run a command (whatever the language is uses) under a different user. There is even a `/savecred` option that allows not to provide the password on each activation but instead save in in the current user's profile.

So if you setup a dedicated user to run the scrip, give it only read permissions on the server folder and run the scrip under that user, then even a bug in the script could not tamper that folder.

BTW, if the script is runned as a scheduled task, you can directly say what user should be used and give its password at config time.